# Cannot open document from database

Tags: c#

I'm saving a document that have spaces in the filename, so the url in the database is:

```
http://wingtipserver/Lists/Knowit.Cv-EmployeeDocumentsListInstance/attachments/2/My Example Pdf File.pdf
```

But when I want to open it in a imagebutton, using `ImageButton.PostBackUrl` then it wont open because the filepath is:

```
http://wingtipserver/Lists/Knowit.Cv-EmployeeDocumentsListInstance/attachments/2/My%20Example%20Pdf%20File.pdf
```

How do i remove the spaces? Or should i do a validation on fileupload so i can't upload documents with spaces?

Comment: You could UrlEncode the url before you write it to the db, then it should match the second version.

Answer (score 0):

The encoded spaces equate directly to spaces, if looking directly at the file system.

Yes, you should normalise your file names, it makes sense not to have spaces, in my opinion, but replace with hyphens or some other 'canonical' character. But, other than that, what happens when you hit the URL? 404? 500? If you told us what you were experiencing then we may suppose an appropriate fix, but as it stands, what you think is the problem shouldn't actually be the problem.

---

To correct myself a bit here, when looking the file up in the database then naturally the strings won't match. In order to overcome this, you should decode the path in the URL before the look-up, using `Server.UrlDecode(urlPart);`

Comment: I can try to validate so no spaces are allowed, right now I'm checking that you only can upload `doc, docx and pdf` with this expression: `(.*\.([Dd][Oo][Cc])|.*\.([Dd][Oo][Cc][Xx])|.*\.([Pp][Dd][Ff])$)` how do i put in so it also don't allow spaces?